# How to find control of dynamically added CheckBoxList into Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I added CheckBoxList dynamically into Panel in asp.net using c#. It's look like dropdownlist.

Now I want bind the selected Items from CheckBoxList to textBox on button click. So before of that I need to find the control.

I trying to find the control like below code but it is not working.

```
CheckBoxList chkLstItem = (CheckBoxList)panlDDL.FindControl("chkLstItem");
```

Comment: Do you rebuild the DOM exactly as it was before you try to find the control?

Comment: I call the function that adding the CheckBoxList into panel on button after selecting some items from CheckBoxList

Comment: I solve this issue by adding only ListItem dynamically into CheckBoxList insted of adding CheckBoxList dynamically into panel, I added CheckBoxList directly. By doing this we can find the control like CheckBoxList chkLstItem =(CheckBoxList)panlDDL.FindControl("chkLstItem");